# object HTMLTextAreaElement in vue js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2

I'm using `"laracasts/utilities"` laravel package to pass laravel variables to js files. Below is my code in my controller:

```
        JavaScript::put([
        'description' => $room->description
    ]);
```

And my vue js code:

```
var keywordcount = new Vue({
el: "#desc-edit",
data: {
    maxdesc: 160,
    desc: description
},
computed: {
    descEdit: function() {
        return this.maxdesc - this.desc.length;
    }
 }
});
```

I'm getting the output `[object HTMLTextAreaElement]` in the textarea of my edit form. I've tried `desc: window.description` as `'js_namespace' => 'window'` is listed in config file.

How can I get the output in plain text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[object HTMLTextAreaElement]` is the textarea DOM element (converted to string). To get its text value, you can add `.value` to the element.

for e.g. if `window.description` is the textarea element, then `window.description.value` gives you the text value. Therefore what you want is probably something like,

```
data: {
    // ...
    desc: window.description.value
},
```